# CGI Died, error log

Tags: lighttpd, cgi, 500-error

I've been getting some 500 internal server errors on my website every so often, so I had a look at the error log.

I am using lighttpd with Kloxo (lxadmin) installed. I have xcache enabled.

```
2011-04-14 04:57:05: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 14160
2011-04-14 04:57:12: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 15363
2011-04-14 04:57:19: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 15492
2011-04-14 04:57:19: (mod_cgi.c.1287) cleaning up CGI: process died with signal 11
2011-04-14 04:57:28: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 15846
2011-04-14 04:57:28: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 15845
2011-04-14 04:57:28: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 15849
2011-04-14 04:57:32: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 15914
2011-04-14 04:58:07: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 17758
2011-04-14 04:58:25: (mod_cgi.c.1287) cleaning up CGI: process died with signal 11
2011-04-14 04:59:57: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 20103
2011-04-14 05:00:05: (mod_cgi.c.588) cgi died, pid: 20363
```

My error log is full of this. Any clues on what's going on?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible conclusion from that log is that the CGI is dying. And from something pretty serious (signal 11 = segmentation fault). You should look at the CGI logs and see if you can debug and find what is making him die so badly.